# For juntamante com o while

Tags: php

Olá, eu estou a criar um BOT de fb e preciso de ajuda, preciso que juntamente com o while do banco de dados preciso de um for que vá de 1 ate ao ultimo registo. Para o usuário poder enviar o código correspondente ao registo!

```
}elseif($text == "BONUS"){
$id_cl = $resexiste->id;                            
$existebonus = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `bonus_attr` WHERE user_id = ? AND usado = ? ORDER by bonus_id desc");
$existebonus->execute(array($id_cl, "0"));
if($existebonus->rowCount() == 0){
    enviaMSG($sender, "Não ha nenhum bonus atribuido a esta conta!");                               
}else{
    enviaMSG($sender, "Envia o codigo correspondente ao bónus que queres usar:");
    while($reseb = $existebonus->fetchObject()){
        $titulo = $reseb->bonus_title;
        enviaMSG($sender, $titulo);
    }
}
}else{
    enviaMSG($sender, "Syntax Invalida!");                              
}
```

Comment: Onde exatamente o `for` entraria aí neste código? E a função do `while` não é justamente percorrer todos os registros? Se sim, qual seria a função do `for`?

Comment: Eu cria o for para isto: 1 - Titulo 1; 2 - Titulo2; mas os títulos veem do banco de dados; a numeração criar que viesse do for

Comment: E o que o `while` está fazendo atualmente?

Comment: Actualmente como esta no código acima postado, ele esta a listar todos os titulos mas sem a numeração

Comment: Então o que precisa não é de um `for`, mas sim de apenas um contador para os títulos?

Comment: sim, e como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a intenção é apenas inserir a numeração junto com o título, basta definir um contador auxiliar e fazer a interpolação:

```
$contador = 1;

while($reseb = $existebonus->fetchObject()){
    $titulo = "{$contador} - {$reseb->bonus_title}";
    enviaMSG($sender, $titulo);
    $contador++;
}
```

Assim, `$titulo` será algo como:

- 1 - Título A
- 2 - Título B
- ...

Comment: Era exactamente isso que procurava, obrigado!